# JGroups to use several network cards

Tags: java, multicast, jgroups

I have a distributed application written in Java which uses JGroups to communicate between different instances of the application located on different machines.

On each machine I have 3 network cards. Each network card has its own IP and they cannot be bridged together as I use them for different purposes as well.

I would like to make the JGroups cluster use simultaneously 2 of the network cards (i.e. bind somehow on 2 IPs), but not the 3rd one...

Is there a possible configuration for this?

Answer (score 1):

You could try to set the bind_addr to *0.0.0.0* to bind to all addresses and then use *receive_interfaces* resp. *send_interfaces* to specify the comma separated list interfaces to receive resp send to. Obviously you would need in this case find a way to create the right configuration file for each machine.

Answer (score 0):

You have to use IP bonding to achieve that.

Comment: I can't use IP bonding as at the same time I have to support a different design which requires 2 different IPs.

Comment: With IP Bonding IIRC you can still bind to the individual NICs, can't you ?

Answer (score 0):

Try using receive_on_all_interfaces and send_on_all_interfaces in your JGROUP configuration.